How to output bpy-based log to console log
Is there anyway to output all info panel log to console log.
I tried this command:
/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/Blender >> log.txt
However, the logs starting with bpy appear in the Info panel but are not output to the console
Also, the following message appears in the console:
Blender[8562:128291] error messaging the mach port for IMKCFRunLoopWakeUpReliable
Could this be related?
